# Increasing performance of clear text file reads

Tags: linux, ubuntu, performance, cache

In our bioinformatics application we have large files (up to 900MB, typically 100MB). These files contain a clear text representation of a genome, and are essentially a 1 line file with a sequence of characters.

Data is referenced by location, for example chromosome 7 starts at position 1 and ends at position 158937463. We typically extract a small section of around 400 characters, eg: from position 4,120,000 4,120,400.

We have a utility written in Ruby for this purpose: https://github.com/sfcarroll/bio-fasta-read and it works by reading through the file from the beginning.

We do these reads many times and they are slowing our application. I was wondering what options are available for caching? The source data will never change, but the ranges will frequently change. We are running Ubuntu Server 14 x64 on a machine with 128GB of RAM.

Is there some OS-level way of increasing performance? Perhaps loading the entire file into memory or somehow caching the requests?

**EDIT**

I should add if there are options such as somehow assigning more memory to the file cache that would help, pointers would be appreciated. We can consider a dedicated server for these file reads if it would need to be tuned in a specific way.

**EDIT 2** 
We are running a Xeon E5-1650 Hexa-Core CPU and dual SSD's (that could be raided), along with 128GB RAM.

Comment: You'd probably be better off heading over to [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). However if you're saying your application reads through the entire file up until the specified offset, then that is definitely wasteful. You'd be better off doing seek operations (`man 2 lseek` for the C documentation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linux kernel does cache management automatically. Everthing that is loaded into RAM, stays there until another process needs RAM and there is no more available. So in the linux kernel RAM should always be full. You system has 128GB of RAM, thats more than enough for a 100-1000MB file.

To load a huge file into RAM just `cat` it:

```
cat huge_file > /dev/null 2>&1
```

All output is sent to `/dev/null`, but for that it must pass the systems RAM. While doing this you can watch how `Cached` in `/proc/meminfo` increases.

When `cat` ends, execute the Ruby application. The Ruby application now reads the cached version of the huge file.

Comment: We have some files which are more frequently read ... if we do this would the file be cycled out of cache, or is there some way to pin it?

Comment: @ardochhigh It gets out of cache only when RAM is full. But there is also an option to mount a part of your RAM and store the file there: `mount -t ramfs ramfs /mountpoint`

Comment: @geedoubleya I said ramfs on purpose, because tmpfs can also allocate swap space. ramfs is 100% system RAM.

Comment: @chaos I sit corrected...

Comment: @chaos so when the server is booted I can create the mountpoint like this **mount -t ramfs ramfs /mountpoint** ie: 100% system ram and the **cp** the files there?

Comment: @ardochhigh Yes, but `/mountpoint` has to exist.

Comment: @ardochhigh And don't forget that after a reboot the file in this /mountpoint are away. So don't move important things there with bo backup

Comment: @chaos thanks you and sorry but 1 last question. Is this method of loading to system ram will likely perform better than **cat**ing the file? Patrick I will also try the seek / code review approach in parallel.

Comment: @ardochhigh ur welcome. And yes that is faster, because `cat`ing the file gives no guarantee that it stays in the RAM or get swapped.

Comment: This won't help. The first time the ruby program will read the file, it will end up in the cache. This will be slightly faster than first doing a useless read just to put the file in the cache, and then doing a read from the cache.

Answer (score 1):

Use `dd` to read a section of a file without reading everything preceding it. 
For your example (reading bytes 4,120,000-4,120,400) you could use

```
dd  bs=400  skip=10300  count=1  if=your_input_file  of=your_output_file
```

This defines a logical block size of 400 bytes,
and then tells `dd` to skip the first 10300 “logical blocks” of the input file (`if`). 
10300 is 4,120,000 ÷ 400. 
Then it reads one block (`count=1`) of 400 bytes and writes it to the output file (`of`). 
If you omit the `of` specification,
`dd` will write to the standard output, so you can pipe it to something.

If the starting point (offset) is not guaranteed
to be an integer multiple of the block size (or even if it is),
you can do trickier stuff, like

```
(dd bs=10000 skip=412 count=0;  dd bs=400 count=1 of=your_output_file) < your_input_file
```

or

```
(dd bs=4120000 skip=1 count=0;  dd bs=400 count=1 of=your_output_file) < your_input_file
```

where

- Again, you can omit the `of` specification, and this will write to the standard output.
- If you run `dd` without an `if` specification, it will read from the standard input. 
  The standard input for the entire `(dd …; dd …)` command group
  comes from the `< your_input_file` at the end.
- The first `dd` command doesn’t read or write any data, because of the `count=0`;
  it only seeks.
- Because the two `dd` commands get their standard input from the same I/O redirection,
  the seek done by the first one will affect the file pointer that the second one sees.

Comment: This is the right approach, but why use `dd`? Using an external utility will slow things down. This should be done directly in the Ruby program.

Comment: It wasn't clear to me whether the Ruby program is an all-in-one solution, or whether it just extracts the 400-byte section and hands it off to another program that does whatever analysis on it. In other words, I thought the above `dd` solution might ***replace*** the Ruby program.